# Safari Auto Fill problem

Tags: safari, auto-complete

At some point I misspelled my name when I typed in my email address to one of the those log in boxes.

Now the misspelling always comes up and fills in and I have to delete it and start over.

I have tried clearing history and cookies and the auto fill feature but it still happens.

How can I clear this and why will it not use my correct one after I type it in.

Comment: I have similar issue and editing AutoFill and Passwords in Safari did not solve the problem. I have also trawled my Contacts folder and my Outlook for Mac address book and my contact is not there, so the erroneous email address is hiding somewhere.
FYI, when I went to post this message as a guest and I was asked for my email address, the erroneous one was offered in some form of autofill!!

Answer (score 1):

You can edit all of your *AutoFill* information under **Safari / Preferences / AutoFill**.

As your issue is with your contact information, you can, even, change it directly from **your** card in the **Address Book** application, as there is where it gets this information from.